# How to enter PDB on a specific stack frame

Tags: python, pdb

I've written a function to enter PDB when an exception is raised (let's call it `trace_on_error`). Right now when I call `pdb.set_trace()` pdb reasonably enters into the stack frame of `trace_on_error`, requiring me to have to type the `up` command before being able to look at the frame of the calling function.

I am trying to make `trace_on_error` not require users to know how its implemented to use, and thus i would like to have pdb enter into the callers stack frame. As I looked for documentation, i was hoping to find something similar to `pdb.set_trace(frame_up=1)`, but I have not found anything.

Example Code:

```
def trace_on_error(f, errors):
    try:
        return f()
    except errors as e:
        pdb.set_trace()
```

if your interested in seeing the full code instead of the minimum snippet please refer here: https://github.com/ethomas2/trace/blob/master/trace.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick (I've tested it but not sure it works in every possible case):

```
def trace_on_error(f, errors):
    try:
        return f()
    except errors as e:
        import sys
        from pdb import Pdb
        Pdb().set_trace(sys._getframe().f_back)
```